# Restricting a SQL Server schema to a single user

Tags: sql, sql-server, security

We have a SQL Server database that will be deployed to client servers. The database contains a number of schemas, some of which we want only the application to access. Is it possible to deny access to all users (even sa) except a user we create to those schemas?

Comment: You can deny access to sa, but he can always take it back. Security Principle: If a user has unrestricted physical access to your computer, it's not your computer anymore

Comment: Are you looking for [Application Roles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190998%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)?

Comment: Application roles look interesting but I don't see how they would allow me to prevent other users (including sa) from access that database. Essentially the data in these schemas should be protected entirely from the owner of the server.

Comment: Object permissions are not checked for the sa, dbo, and db_owner role.  You can't prevent privileged accounts from accessing schemas and data within.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot remove the `SA` out of the permissions. Every person who is SA can see and work with your data. It doesn't count which schema it is in. Another option for an `SA` is the usage of `DBCC`, which will help him avoid some principles (like the one that a temporary table is only visible to the session which generated it).

If you trust a person to be an `SA`, you really should trust him to access all of your data.

The only way to avoid this, is to wait for SQL Server 2016. It will allow you to store every data in your database encrypted. Even the SQL Server itself can't access all information of it. The decryption/encryption is done by the application. SQL Server self don't know the key. The new features will be called `always encrypted`.

Anyway, you can do such a scenario on your own with nearly all SQL Server variants, but it would be a bit more work as in SQL Server 2016.